# SSRS Report Builder 3.0 Row Grouped records count

Tags: reporting-services, report, reportbuilder, reportbuilder3.0

Need help to display the grouped row count in report builder.

I want to get the rowcount of grouped records.
RowCounts("DatasetName") is giving the total rowcount of the dataset but if the dataset is grouped in reports it still gives the total row count. i want to display the grouped records count. Thanks in advance.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more details, screen shot or example results?

Comment: Thanks got it working by using CountRows method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `=CountRows()` or `=CountRows("Group_Description")` instead, where "Group_Description" is whatever you've named the group.