# Change the font color of a Total row in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

In the below screen shot I have built a report using a matrix. I have a working expression that changes the color of the columns "Avg Wait AD" and Avg Wait Other". I use static numbers to identify the ranges for the colors. Now I need a expression that can change the color of the "Consolidated" row. The consolidated column is just a *Total* row (Or a calculated row) that I've added. The problem I'm having is that in each day, I can have between 1-3 items (Consolidated is not considered an item). I'm stuggling with getting the amount of items there are in the day so I can use that in my calculation. My expression would look something like

`=IIF(Sum(Fields!Avg_Wait_Time___AD.Value) >= (CurrentItemsInDay * 60), "Red", IIF(Fields!Avg_Wait_Time___AD.Value < (CurrentItemsInDay * 60) AND Fields!Avg_Wait_Time___AD.Value >= (CurrentItemsInDay * 28), "Orange", "Green"))`

(I'm just using CurrentItemsInDay for illustration purposes)

[image]

Comment: I assume you have made a group and then set a total after each group. Select the gray tab next to the row you want the font to have a different colour and add your expression to the Color property.

Comment: @Snowlockk I know how to change the font color just fine. I need to know how to get the count of items in the group (Day) so I can use that in my expression.

Comment: Possibly this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320495/total-row-count-for-grouped-values-in-ssrs-2008?

Comment: Using CountRows() was the key. I was looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505651/ssrs-report-builder-3-0-row-grouped-records-count as you posted your comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSRS Report Builder 3.0 Row Grouped records count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505651/ssrs-report-builder-3-0-row-grouped-records-count)